# Input text type not shown in safari

Tags: html, css

I have something in this code that breaks my `<input type = "text">` from showing in safari, Im not sure what it is can anyone help me?

```
    input[type="text"]{
border: 3px solid #eae9ef;
border-radius: 3px !important;
box-sizing: border-box !important;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0) !important;
padding:1.5em 1em !important; 
}
```

The issue is because of the `padding 1.5em 1em`, how can I fix it,I need the padding to make the input box bigger, but with it my text disappears.

Comment: You have multiple inputs so which one of them? Or all? Narrow down your code to the minimum and leave the bits which a required  for showing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a height to the text input instead of adding padding. The padding will limit the space inside the input so the text won't show.